# Strategy of interaction with the employer when applying for a job in a foreign company

Tags: resume, employer-relations, cover-letter, psychology

I am planning to get a job in a foreign aerospace company. It is so atypical and unusual for me, it seems complicated and long, potentially life-changing. But this is the way to achieve my goals.

Therefore, just one stage of submitting a resume, a cover letter and communicating with the employer already makes me worried and nervous.

At the same time, I understand very well that the risk of employer refusal is quite high. But I'm not going to give up. And I would like to increase the chances of employment by supplementing text materials (CV and cover letter) with competent interaction with the employer.

My questions are:

1. What is the strategy for communicating with a potential employer in the event of a rejection?
2. How to maintain communication with him and which ones should or should not be spoken to?
3. How often should I remind about myself and send resume again?
4. Is it worth it to agree or offer to do an internship?

Comment: Are they advertising for international applicants? Have they said they'll do VISA sponsorships?

Comment: Don't just apply. Find a referral first within the company, and then apply. If they reject you. Say thank you and move on (usually, they'll tell you when you're allowed to apply again. Usually the period is 1 year or 6 months depending on how well you did in the interview). And if you're applying to Space X, know that they can only hire US citizens and green card holders. They have no choice in the matter. For other space related companies, it may be the same thing. I don't know. Do your research. Since you haven't given us the country in question or the company name, we can't really help you.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie read my answer to StephanBranczyk

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yes, I got a little familiar with the rules of employment in American aerospace companies. At such a high level, I do not apply yet. Maybe in the future, we'll see. At this stage, I would like to start with ICEYE, Finland. In general, I understood what needs to be done. Thank you!

Comment: Nobody likes a stalker, including employers. "I'm not giving up" makes it more and more unlikely that someone will hire you.

Comment: @gnasher729 No, this means that I will continue to improve my resume, cover letter and look for work elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that you first need to understand the immigration/visa/sponsoring process that's applicable to your current citizenship and the desired country of employment. These tend to be complicated and nuanced, so I recommend going deep there.

Understand what employment models do exist (working remotely, start with local subsidiary, temporary work visa, permanent residency, naturalization, etc.) which ones are interesting to you, what the different potential paths might look like, and what the typical time line and success rates with people of your background (nationality, academic level, years of experience, specific field) are.

Then look for job postings that explicitly state that at least one of your possible paths is available.

> What is the strategy for communicating with a potential employer in the event of a rejection?

None really. In all cases a rejection is a rejection and no follow up is needed other than a polite "thanks for considering my application".

> How to maintain communication with him and which ones should or should not be spoken to?

You speak to employers that advertise jobs and an employment path that you are interested in. Apply to the job posting and answer when they reach out to you.

> How often should I remind about myself and send resume again?

That's typically a waste of time. If you don't hear back, they are not interested.

> Is it worth it to agree or offer to do an internship?

Yes, if you are financially ok with it and it fits into one of your "master immigration" plans.

Comment: Sometimes it is recommended not to burn bridges, but to ask for feedback - what exactly did the employer not like in my candidacy?  This will help to work on the mistakes, will give valuable experience for the future.  Is it worth doing or is it bad advice?